# Enlargement-how to enlarge a shape by negative scale factor

Tags: geometry

The diagram shows a shaded shape. Enlarge the shaded shape by scale factor $\frac{-1}{2}$ with centre of enlargement of $(-1,0)$.

[image: wording]

Hi could someone tell me how I would do this please I'm very confused on how to enlarge this shape by negative half scale factor. Does it become flipped?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have to make an homothetic transformation.

If $A$ is the center of your homothetic transformation (here, $(-1,0)$) and $k$ your homothetic factor (here, $-1/2$), the image of the point $X$ is $X'$ such that it verifies the following equation:

$$k\vec{AX}=\vec{AX'}$$

So, here, you have to calculate $k\vec{AX}$ for each vertex $X$ of your shape. And it will give:

[image: homothetic transformation]

Basically, if you want to construct the image of $X=(x,y)$ by an homothetic transformation of center $A=(a,b)$ and factor $k$, you have to do the following:

1. Draw the line $AX$
2. Calculate the distance $|AX|$ (using their respective coordinates). This distance is $|AX|=\sqrt{(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}}$.
3. If $k$ is positive, draw a vector on the line $AX$ going from $A$ to the same side of $X$ and of length $k|AX|$. You have now the image $X'$ of $X$.
   If $k$ is negative, draw a vector on the line $AX$ going from $A$ to the opposite side of $X$ and of length $|k||AX|$. You now have the image $X'$ of $X$.

Comment: thanks I will try to understand this a bit better do you know any revision that would help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know any revision. But what you have to do to construct it is the following. First, to find the image of a point $X=(x,y)$ by an homothetic transformation of center $(a,b)$ and factor $k$, you have to calculate the vector $\vec{AX}=(x-a,y-b)$. Then, you multiply by $k$, so that you obtain $(kx-ka,ky-kb)=\vec{AX}'$ and you now have the image of $X$ in the cartesian plane.

Comment: i emailed you could you message me please on gmail

Comment: It is better to stay on this website. I'll improve my answer, so that you understand perfectly how to construct the image of your shape.

Comment: on my table are the coordinates (-4,-1),(-2,-1),(-4,-2),(-3,-2),(-3,-5) and (-2,-5)

Comment: What are these coordinates? Maybe I mislead you with my previous comment. Check my updated answer for more informations.

Comment: what would the coordinates be of the new shape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31288/discussion-between-super123-and-moebiuscorzer).